# Override Jinja block in included template from extending template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a Flask project with the Materialize CSS framework. I would like to add `class="active"` to `li` element in navigation menu based on the current page the user is viewing. My main template includes a template with the menu, the menu defines a block for each item's class. The rendered template extends main and overrides one of the blocks, but that doesn't work. How can I override a block defined in an include?

`main.html`

```
<div class="menu_container">
    {% include "menu_items.html"%}
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

`menu_items.html`

```
<li class="{% block home_active %}{% endblock %}">Homepage</li>
<li class="{% block other_page_active %}{% endblock %}">Other Page</li>
```

`homepage.html`

```
{% extends main.html %}
{% block home_active %}active{% endblock %} #Trying to add class active, doesn't work.
{% block body %}
    # Homepage content goes here
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This behavior seems logical, but currently you cannot override an included block from a child template. This feature has been [implemented](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/243) once, but got reverted because it had some backward-incompatible side effects.

But there's a workaround of course. The simplest solution is to put every block definition in the `main.html` template, then extending it in `homepage.html` will work.

The second solution is to use a global variable, since assignments in child templates are global and executed before the template is evaluated. Here is an example:

`main.html`

Here we define a variable `active_item`, which can be override from a child template. We set a default value for it as well.

```
{% set active_item = active_item|default('home') %}
<div class="menu_container">
    {% include "menu_items.html"%}
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

`menu_items.html`

We add the `active` class to an item depending of `active_item` variable.

```
<li class="{% if active_item == 'home' %}active{% endif %}">Homepage</li>
<li class="{% if active_item == 'other' %}active{% endif %}">Other Page</li>
```

`homepage.html`

In this template we set a value to the `active_item` variable.

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}    
{% set active_item = 'home' %}

{% block body %}
    # Homepage content goes here
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This is going to be super helpful to a lot of people out there! Has there been an update to this approach since 2016?

Comment: @Aeva No, it still has this limitation. See [the latest 3.1 docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#include): "the current template cannot override any blocks that the included template outputs".