# Render specific Jinja content blocks in main page upon button click

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2

Hi guys as you will see below, I am a complete newbie to jinja blocks and how to manage them and would highly appreciate your help

main.html

```
<html>
<head><head>
<body> 
<li>about us</li>
<li>Our services</li>
 <body>
</html>
```

The idea is to render a jinja content block on li clicked in the main body:

so for example, if the user clicks on the li named "about us", I would like to render the content block named "about us" which extends this base template

And if the user clicks our services, I would like to render the content block named "our services" which extends this base template.

the about us block content is an HTML file and looks like the one below:
about-us.html

```
{% extends main.html %}
{% block aboutus %}
<p> ABOUT US INFORMATION</p> <!-- for example -->
{% endblock %}
```

the our services block content is an HTML file and looks like the one below:
ourservices.html

```
{% extends main.html %}
{% block ourservices %}
<p> OUR SERVICES</p> <!-- for example -->
{% endblock %}
```

Finally, I would like to know if it's possible to change the URL of my page when I go to any of these options:

```
from application import app
from flask import render_template, request, Flask
@app.route("/main.html")
def main():
return render_template("main.html", index=True)
```

so the idea is if I click on about us, the URL will change to main/about-us and should render the following:

and the URL looking like main/about-us

```
<html>
<head><head>
<body> 
<p> About us</p>
 <body>
</html>
```

and services should look like main/services

```
<html>
<head><head>
<body> 
<p> OUR SERVICES</p>
 <body>
</html>
```

I would highly appreciate your help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me if you intend for these to be distinct pages or just sections on the same page.

If sections on the same page, then why not just render all the content and hide the sections you don't initially need. When user clicks a button, you can then unhide the relevant section.

Comment: sounds like a great option hiding the content, however, I also wanted to change the URL based on the block content rendered in the main page. I am wondering if that is possible

Comment: I am wondering if something similar to the following is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40537752/override-jinja-block-in-included-template-from-extending-template?rq=1